# puppet: how to purge a package/server by module

Tags: mongodb, puppet

I  have puppetlab mongodb  module   https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/mongodb  installed on my linux  ubuntu 12.04 . I can install mongodb by manifest script

site.pp

```
node default{
   include mongodb
}
```

but how do I purge mongodb through this module ?

Comment: http://www.puppetcookbook.com/posts/remove-package.html

Purged nukes config files.  Absent merely removes the module.

Answer (score 1):

try adding a:

```
  package{'mongodb':
    ensure => purged,
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

`include` is a shortcut alias to the `class` description.

Therefore:

`include mongodb`

is the same as

`class {"mongodb": ensure => present }`

Meaning you can remove it with

`class {"mongodb": ensure => absent }`